# QIWI API проверка платежа, комментария

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Добрый день, нуждаюсь в помощи составления регулярного выражения, свои знания имеются, но речь идет про проверку выполнено платежа  на сайте, по этому не хотел бы рисковать делать это путем собственный знаний.

При помощи QIWI Api идёт получение входящих платежей, далее идут многократные проверки, и я остановился на примечании.

Платеж выполненный на моем сайте, имеет следующий комментарий к переводу: `Пополнение баланса #2` где после **#** идёт строго цифра, номер заказа.

Как распознать, попадает ли текущий комментарий, под данный формат? Вариантов множество, делать строчные проверки, разбивать на массив,  и сверять значения, но мне кажется что в таком случае, самое верное решение это прибегнуть к помощи regexp.

Comment: с qiwi не работал, но что-то я сомневаюсь, что для проверки платежа нужны регулярные выражения, как правило агрегатор платежной системы должен вернуть ответ в удобоваримом формате типа json

Comment: @Peresada киви возвращает массив последних платежей, со всем и данными, и нужно проверить где платеж который относится к сайту, а где частный перевод

Comment: предоставьте тогда пример этого массива, можете затереть конфиденциальные данные, я не думаю, что там требуются регулярки

Comment: Я глянул что возвращает qiwi в своем API. По факту, когда совершается платеж на сайте, киви должен вернуть ответ о конкретно этом платеже, а Вы (т.е. сайт) должен записать номер этой транзакции в базу. Далее, чтобы определить какие платежи были с сайта, а какие нет, вы просто сверяете номера транзакций в базе и в массиве, который получили от qiwi.

Comment: @Peresada заказ формируется заранее, после чего пользователю генерируется комментарий к переводу, в котором указан номер заказа, после получения api идет сверка данных, с данными заказа в бд.  И сейчас я остановился на проверке комментария, и нужно определить, где комментарий который относится к сайту, к примеру как тут - [comment] => Пополнение баланса #2 а где частный перевод, который к заказу не относится, к примеру как тут - [comment] => На новый монитор

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Составил такое регулярное выражение:

```
$a = 'Пополнение баланса #10';
preg_match('/^(Пополнение баланса) #([0-9]+)$/', $a, $match);

print_r($match);

Array
(
    [0] => Пополнение баланса #10
    [1] => Пополнение баланса
    [2] => 10
)
```

P.S. хотелось бы узнать, можно ли его "обмануть"? Вроде бы тестирую, пока срабатывает точно.

Answer (score 1):

Если данные приходят в массиве, то и проверять надо массив. Или же проходить по массиву циклом *(или одной из подходящих для этого функций)*.

Соответствия по массиву можно искать с помощью php-функции `preg_grep()`. Скобки `()` в шаблоне для этой задачи использовать не нужно *(если конечно вам не нужно по отдельности получать значения из комментария)*. Публикую решение для двумерного массива:

```
$array = [
    ['comment' => 'Пополнение баланса #2'],
    ['comment' => 'На новый монитор'],
    ['comment' => 'Пополнение баланса #10']
];

array_map(function($a) use(&$match) {
    $arr = preg_grep('~^Пополнение баланса #\d+$~', $a);
    !$arr ?: $match[] = $arr['comment'];
}, $array);

var_dump($match);
```